# Gatling not logging request/response

Tags: logback, gatling

Gatling is not logging anything (errors, request body, response body etc) even though I am using default logback.xml. Does anyone know what is missing?

```
<statusListener class="ch.qos.logback.core.status.NopStatusListener" />

<appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%-5level] %logger{15} - %msg%n%rEx</pattern>
        <immediateFlush>false</immediateFlush>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<!-- Uncomment for logging ALL HTTP request and responses -->
<logger name="io.gatling.http.ahc" level="TRACE" />
<logger name="io.gatling.http.response" level="TRACE" />
<!-- Uncomment for logging ONLY FAILED HTTP request and responses -->
<!-- <logger name="io.gatling.http.ahc" level="DEBUG" /> -->
<!-- <logger name="io.gatling.http.response" level="DEBUG" /> -->

<root level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
</root>
```

Answer (score 1):

Question was answered on the [Gatling mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gatling/UsfrdHzoeoc).

This issue is that CyberNinja has 2 slf4j implementation in his classpath (the logback Gatling provides plus one he added himself) so it fails to start.

And as he also configured a `NopStatusListener` (which is not here in Gatling's standard logback.xml file), slf4j fails silently.

Comment: Hi Stephane, I removed slf4j implementation provided by gatling and kept the one from my jar. Still nothing is getting logged.

Comment: I am sure I am missing something but hitting a wall identifying that. Any help with this would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to add

```
<contextListener class="ch.qos.logback.classic.jul.LevelChangePropagator">
        <resetJUL>true</resetJUL>
</contextListener>
```

Comment: Tried this one. Still not logging anything.